# How to get the first div element on event listener

Tags: javascript, html

I have below HTML:

```
<div id="parent">
  <div>
    <div>
      //needs to get the inner HTML of this.
    </div>
    <p>
    </p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div>
      //needs to get the inner HTML of this.
    </div>
    <p>
    </p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div>
      //needs to get the inner HTML of this.
    </div>
    <p>
    </p>
  </div>
  ...10 more
</div>
```

Could someone please confirm if is it possible to have one click event listener to capture the inner HTML of grandchild of the parent node on mouse click?

I have tried using below

```
 document.getElementById('parent').addEventListener('click', event => {

  // what to do here to get the inner HTML of granchild div 
})
```

The problem with above approach is if I click on grand child p tag then it gives the inner html of p tag but I always want the inner html of the first div.

Comment: It is absolutely possible. What exactly are you struggling with? What does this have to do with event listening?

Comment: I am sorry, I have updated my question

Comment: Why does it say you want to get the innerHTML of all 3 grandchildren, not just the first one?

Comment: I dont want all 3 grandchildren, if I click on first child, I want first grand child if 2nd then 1st grandchild of 2nd child and if I click on P tag I still need inner html of first div

Comment: But it says `//needs to get the inner HTML of this.` in all 3 grandchildren.

Comment: I am sorry, that's my bad, I don't need all 3 of them at once

Comment: @Barmar I don't find those comments misleading. (although I find the js comments in html interesting)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `event.target.closest("div")` and check if has `firstElementChild` it means you click on `p` tag and `firstElementChild` gives you the correct `div` and if it is `null` it means you already click on corrcet `div`.

Here is working sample:

```js
document.getElementById('parent').addEventListener('click', event => {
 
    var firstDiv = event.target.closest("div").firstElementChild;
    
    if(!firstDiv)
         firstDiv = event.target;
         
    console.log(firstDiv.innerHTML);

})
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div>
     <div>
       1. needs to get the inner HTML of this.
     </div>
     <p>
       1.P
     </p>
  </div>
 <div>
     <div>
       2.needs to get the inner HTML of this.
     </div>
     <p>
      2.P
     </p>
  </div>
 <div>
     <div>
       3.needs to get the inner HTML of this.
     </div>
     <p>
       3.P
     </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: They all have the same inner HTML, how can you tell which one is being printed?

Comment: @Barmar I changed the each text of div and p. as you can see it depends on your target. Am I right?

Answer (score 1):

Please use this code.

```
document.getElementById("parent").addEventListener("click", function() {
    console.log(this.children[0].innerHTML);
});
```

Comment: this would always return 1st grand child

Comment: unfortunately, this is always blank for me

Answer (score 0):

If you want to attach event listener to each of the grandchild div, then

```
document.getElementById('.grandchild-div-id').forEach(item => {
  item.addEventListener('click', event => {
    //handle click
  })
})
```

Comment: the problem with this is if I click on p tag it return the inner HTML of p but I alwasy want the inner html of div not the 2nd p tag

Comment: @gs650x you mean if user click on p still you need innerHtml of first dive?

Comment: @gs650x Or you mean click event must be work only on first div?

Answer (score 0):

- Read more about js dom

```
var parent = document.getElementById("parent")
parent.addEventListener("click", function() {
   var children = this.children;
   for(var i of children) {
    console.log(i.innerHTML)
   }
});
```

Comment: unfortunately, this doesn't serve the purpose

Comment: You keep editting your question can you just say what you want ?